# Function that modifies string and returns the modified string

Tags: c, concatenation, c-strings, function-definition

I have a function that takes a string from a macro. It modifies the string and then returns a new modified string. My intention is to use this returned string. However, it does not work, as it does not return the modified string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"

#define ENCRYPTED_FILE  "hello.txt"

char *decrypt(){
    char str[]=ENCRYPTED_FILE;
    strtok(str,".txt");
    strcat(str,"_decrypted.txt");
    //printf("%s\n",str);
    return str;
};
   
int main()
{        
    printf("%s\n",decrypt());     //output: *** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Q: What is the size of `str`? How long of a string can it hold?

Comment: large enough to hold the "hello_decrypted.txt" string

Comment: Why do you think that is exactly?

Comment: I increased the size now char str[40]=ENCRYPTED_FILE; still error

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function returns a pointer to the first element of the local array `str` with automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function.

So as a result the function returns an invalid pointer.

You need to allocate memory for the array dynamically.

Also this call of `strtok`

```
strtok(str,".txt");
```

does not make a sense. The function does not search the sub-string `".txt"`. It searches the first character of the set of characters specified by the string `".txt"`.  Instead you could use the function `strstr`.

And this code `strcat`

```
 strcat(str,"_decrypted.txt");
```

invokes undefined behaviour because the target array does not have enough space to store the appended string literal.

The function can look for example like it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ENCRYPTED_FILE  "hello.txt"

char *decrypt( void )
{
    const char *encrypted_file = ENCRYPTED_FILE;
    
    const char *p = strstr( encrypted_file, ".txt" );
    
    if ( p == NULL ) p = encrypted_file + strlen( encrypted_file );
    size_t n = p - encrypted_file;
    
    const char *decrypted_file = "_decrypted.txt";
    
    char *s = malloc( n + strlen( decrypted_file ) + 1 );
    
    memmove( s, encrypted_file, n );
    s[n] = '\0';

    strcat( s + n, decrypted_file );

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s = decrypt();
    
    puts( s );
    
    free( s );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
hello_decrypted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a pointer to a temporary array which becomes dangling after control leaves the function. First, you'll have to allocate it on heap, via `malloc`, and next, make sure its allocated size is enough to contain the original size plus the extra "_decrypted" suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed your library notation as `#include "string.h"` instead of `#include <string.h>` that might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are making bad use of the `strtok()` function.  It will split a string into substrings each time it finds a dot `.`, a `t`, or an `x`.  As you have written the code I'm afraid this is not what you want (to eliminate the `.txt` suffix?)

Read the manual page of `strtok()` as it will explain exactly what this function actually does.

On the other side, you cannot truncate the string at the start of `.txt` and then append a longer string to it.  When you declared the `str[]` array (by explicitly not using a length) the compiler reserved as many characters to hold the text comming from the macro, plus one more to hold the `\0` delimiter.  So your array has only space to hold 10 characters (the 9 of `"hello.txt"`, plus one for the `'\0'` end of string).  Of course, there's no place there to hold `hello_decripted.txt` which would need 19 characters plus one more for the `\0`.  A workaround to this problem could be to indicate in the array declaration how many characters you want the compiler to use, as in:

```
    char str[100] = ENCRYPTED_FILE;
```

and then you can extend upto 100 characters (99 plus a holder for the string end char `\0`).

If you find the string you search for (`.txt`) and put a `\0` in the first position of it, you'll truncate the original string and you'll be able to do what you actually want, that is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"  /* is this what you actually mean and not <string.h>? */

#define ENCRYPTED_FILE  "hello.txt"

char *decrypt(){
    char str[100]=ENCRYPTED_FILE;
    char *p = strstr(str,".txt");
    if (p != NULL) {  /* the string actually has a .txt suffix */
        *p = '\0'; /* string truncated */
    }
    strcat(str,"_decrypted.txt"); /* add new suffix */
    //printf("%s\n",str);
    /* you cannot return str as str is a local variable,
     * and it will cease to exist as soon as we leave this
     * function body, better return a new dynamically
     * allocated string (that need to be freed with free(3)
     */
    return strdup(str);
};
   
int main()
{        
    /* the stack smashing probably is due to returning the
     * address of a local variable, that ceased to exist.
     */
    char *name = decrypt();
    printf("%s\n", name);
    free(name); /* return the memory allocated in decrypt() */
    return 0;
}
```

This will solve the problem respecting your intentions.  But you are wrong in another point:

What if the string `.txt` appears just before the end of the original name?  In my opinion, what you are searching for is for a `.txt` suffix (what was earlier known as an *extension*)  What impedes your file to be named something like `blahblah.txt01.txt`? --which has two occurences of the substring `.txt`--) This is not the correct algorithm to search for a `.txt` suffix.  The  correct way is to search if `.txt` is **at the end of the string**, and for that, the algorithm to use is different (and far more efficient):

```
char *decrypt(){
    char str[100]=ENCRYPTED_FILE;
    char *suff = ".txt";
    /* go to the point that is strlen(str) further than
     * the beginning of the string minus the string
     * of the suffix */
    char *p = str + strlen(str) - strlen(suff);
    if (strcmp(p, suff) == 0) {  /* the string actually has a .txt suffix */
        *p = '\0'; /* string truncated */
    }
    /* from this point on, everything goes the same */
    strcat(str,"_decrypted.txt"); /* add new suffix */
    //printf("%s\n",str);
    return strdup(str);
};
```

in this case you only need to do one string comparison (which is done multiple times in the body of `strstr()` to search for a full match) and you'll know if it fails or not quickly and efficiently.

## Note

A final note about the `#include "string.h"` line in your code:  Including a file with double quotes instead of a pair of `<>` characters is ok if you have a local file (in your local directory) that is called the same as some library file, because that will make it to be found before the system library one.  But it is a bad habit if you include the standard library include file, because if you later decide to create an include file (in other module or program) and create a local `string.h` file, this program will suddenly start to compile with errors and you'll not guess why.  Be careful about `#include` names and the two ways of calling them.  Files named as `<file.h>` are normally standard library include files, and are searched for in fixed places in the system.  Files named as `"file.h"` are searched first in the working directory, and if not found, then they are searched in the library fixed paths.  Try to use `"` only for your files or files you have in your build directory, and search system files only with `<` & `>`.